# Comparing the contents of two lists

Tags: python

I have the following list of lists:

```
winValues = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]]
```

Lets say the player variables are:

```
[6,3,2,4,2]
```

How can i check if the player has a set of three winning numbers?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

Never mind, i solved this :-)

```
for elem in winValues:
        if elem[0] in playerValues and elem[1] in playerValues and elem[2] in playerValues:
            print("Win!")
```